# Visual C++ Can't Properly fill Constructor Requirements

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constructor

So I can't seem to properly fill the requirements for this constructor.

```
DIVA_STATUS DIVA_getObjectDetailsList (
IN BOOL                   pFirstTime,
IN time_t                 *initialTime,
IN int                    pListType,
IN int                    pObjectsListType,
IN int                    pMaxListSize,
IN DIVA_STRING            pObjectName,
IN DIVA_STRING            pObjectCategory
IN DIVA_STRING            pMediaName
DIVA_LEVEL_OF_DETAIL      pLevelOfDetail,
IN vector<DIVA_STRING>    listPosition,
OUT vector<DIVA_OBJECT_DETAILS_LIST>      *&pObjectDetailsList
)
```

The problem seems to be the last line which outputs a vector of classes (???). I'm a little rusty with C++ so I cant recall why you would dereference a reference call (*&).

DIVA_OBJECT_DETAILS_LIST is a class shown below:

```
class DIVA_OBJECT_DETAILS_LIST {
public:
int                            listType;
DIVA_STRING                    siteID;
vector<DIVA_STRING>            *listPosition;
vector<DIVA_OBJECT_INFO>       *objectInfo;
vector<DIVA_OBJECT_TAPE_INFO>  *objectTapeInfo;
};
```

Here is what I get when I try compiling using VC++ 2008 Express

```
1>Compiling...
1>initiator.cpp
1>.\initiator.cpp(148) : error C2100: illegal indirection
1>.\initiator.cpp(148) : error C2665: 'DIVA_getObjectDetailsList' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
1>        z:\Mediavault1\Automation\DIVA_API\DIVArchiveAPI\CppAPI Test\include\DIVAapi.h(2191): could be 'DIVA_STATUS DIVA_getObjectDetailsList(bool,time_t,int,int,int,DIVA_STRING,DIVA_STRING,DIVA_STRING,DIVA_LEVEL_OF_DETAIL,std::vector<_Ty>,DIVA_OBJECT_DETAILS_LIST *&)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=DIVA_STRING
1>        ]
1>        while trying to match the argument list '(bool, time_t, int, int, int, DIVA_STRING, DIVA_STRING, DIVA_STRING, DIVA_LEVEL_OF_DETAIL, std::vector<_Ty>, DIVA_OBJECT_DETAILS_LIST *)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=DIVA_STRING
1>        ]
```

Here is how I'm calling the constructor:

```
cr = DIVA_getObjectDetailsList (
                   _firstTime,
                   (time_t)_initDate,
                   (int)DIVA_OBJECTS_LIST,
                   (int)DIVA_OBJECTS_CREATED_SINCE,
                   _size,
                   _name,
                   _category,
                   _group,
                   DIVA_INSTANCE,
                   *_listType.listPosition,
                   &*_listType
                   );
```

_listType is DIVA_OBJECT_DETAILS_LIST. How do I pass it pointer by reference?

Comment: How are you attempting to call the constructor?

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be with the second to last argument. You are passing a `std::vector<DIVA_STRING>*` when you should just be passing a `std::vector<DIVA_STRING>` (not a pointer).

But to help your understanding about the last argument, `vector<DIVA_OBJECT_DETAILS_LIST>*&` is a "reference to pointer to `vector<DIVA_OBJECT_DETAILS_LIST>`" type. That is, you should pass a pointer and it is passed by reference.

Comment: Well, don't you have some internal contradiction in your answer? first you say "not a pointer", then - "pointer"

Comment: @Lol4t0 Different argument. I should make that clear. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my constructor and output from the compiler. Can't seem to match up the last constructor with whats required...

Comment: @user2359758 What is a `DIVA_STRING`? Is a `std::string` convertible to a `DIVA_STRING`?

Comment: @user2359758 Also, what are the types of `listType.listPosition` and `listType`?

Comment: A DIVA_STRING is a std:string (something that's defined in the preprocessor of the API). And _listType is a DIVA_OBJECT_DETAILS_LIST and listPosition is variable within _listType